# Netbeans - "Entity Classes from Database" Creates Empty Class Files

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans

Just as the title says, netbeans can see my database and all of its tables, the import instantly finishes and i get empty class files, just as if i did new -> class and entered the name

Edit: I have realised that it works correctly on some types of projects while it fails on others. All with the same database

Comment: Having the same issue. I'll update if I find anything

Comment: Likewise (Apache NetBeans IDE 12.2)

Comment: @ShaneKnowles did you have any luck solving the issue?

Comment: I switched to Netbeans 12.0 and it seems to work fine

Comment: @Dan thanks. Actually I ended up getting it with 12.2. The issue seemed to be the auto-generated files contradict each other. So while it defaulted to transaction-type="JSF" in the persistence-unit, it had to be "RESOURCE_LOCAL" to actually work with the other autogenerated things. At least iirc that was all I needed to do (among restarting glassfish several times)

Comment: @ShaneKnowles Ah interesting. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

same here (Netbeans 12.3)!

However, it only happens if you do not select all tables, but only select certain ones.

An empty 'example' project could create the entities when all tables were selected. I then copied the affected new tables out of the 'example' project.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem with Netbeans 12.2. It works now, after I changed to Netbeans 12.0

Comment: This is not an answer to the post as it is just a suggestion. Please add comments instead of answers for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 12.2, and I'm experiencing the same problem. If I create several new Entities, some of the entities are created empty.

To solve the empty entities, I deleted them one by one and then recreate them one at a time. This takes a lot of time, but at least it's working.

Comment: Ended up switching from 12.2 to 12.0, I was tired of generating entities one by one.